# Route in Rails: bad URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

The problem is that when I click on the link, the URL looks like:

```
/show?id=1&slug=aasdasd
```

But should be:

```
/strona/1/aasdasd
```

In routes.rb

```
match "strona/:id/:slug", :controller => "subpages", :action => "show", :via => :get
```

In application_controller.rb:

```
def subpages
 Subpage.all
end
```

In application.html.erb:

```
<% subpages.each do |subpage| %>
  <%= link_to subpage.title, {:controller => 'subpages', :action => 'show', :id => subpage.id, :slug => subpage.title.parameterize} %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes.rb (add ":as => :strona" for your path):

```
match "strona/:id/:slug", :controller => "subpages", :action => "show", :via => :get, :as => :strona
```

View.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to subpage.title, strona_path(subpage.id, subpage.title.parameterize) %>
```